# calculate n for nlog(n) and n! when time is 1 second. (algorithm takes f(n) microseconds)

Tags: algorithm, big-o, clrs

given the following problem from CLRS algo book.

> For each function f (n) and time t in the following table, determine
>   the largest size n of a problem that can be solved in time t, assuming
>   that the algorithm to solve the problem takes f(n) microseconds.

1. how can one calculate n for f(n)=nlog(n) when time is 1 second?
2. how can one calculate n for f(n)=n! when time is 1 second?

Answer (score 1):

It is mentioned that the algorithm takes f(n) microseconds. Then, one may consider that algorithm to consist of f(n) steps each of which takes 1 microsecond.

The questions given state that relevant f(n) values are bound by 1 second. (i.e. 10<sup>6</sup> microseconds) Then, since you are looking for the largest n possible to fulfill those conditions, your questions boil down to the inequalities given below.

**1)** f(n) = nlog(n) <= 10<sup>6</sup>

**2)** f(n) = n! <= 10<sup>6</sup>

The rest, I believe, is mainly juggling with algebra and logarithmic equations to find the relevant values.

Answer (score 0):

In first case, You can refer to [Example of newtons method to calculate cube root](https://socratic.org/questions/how-do-you-use-newton-s-method-to-approximate-the-value-of-cube-root) Newton’s method to approximate the roots or [Lambert W Function](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-solve-for-n-in-the-following-equation-n-log-n-1000). It may help to calculate value of n. As per the my findings mostly there is no other analytical approach can help.

In second case, python script can help to calculate n with manual approch.

```
def calFact(n):
    if(n == 0 or n==1):
        return n
    return n*calFact(n-1)

nVal=1
while(calFact(nVal)<1000000):         # f(n) = n! * 10^-6 sec
    nVal=nVal+1                       # 10^6 = n!

print(nVal)
```

So in this case we are trying to find out n such that n! is equal to or near to 10^6.